# Huge size of dll after migrating to vs2017

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017

I'm porting some projects from vs2010 to vs2017, but I experienced a very strange behaviour: the size of dll built with vs2017 is far greater than vs2010 one:
4.636 Kb vs 595 kb (release version) !!!!!

What I did was:

1. 1 copy vs 2010 project with name test
2. open test.vcxproj with 2017
   and accept the conversion of toolset (from vs2010 to vs2017)
3. build
   the dll in release version.

I used dumpbin to try understanding something and I found that the size of initialized data is greater (hex values):

```
      422600 size of initialized data   VS2017
       28200 size of initialized data   VS2010
```

Any idea why the difference and how to correct? 
TIA

Comment: do you link statically or dynamically with C-Runtime? Just to filter out a possibility that this data is from grown up C-Runtime

Comment: @Gruffalo : dynamically link for both cases

Comment: did you check another project?

Comment: What libraries are you linking to? Do you use MFC? There are countless possibilities and changes from VS 2010 to 2017.

Comment: Perhaps formerly uninitialized global data is now initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

There is a different behaviour of vs2010 c++ compiler vs vs2017 on how the compiler prefers to initialize static data even with the same optimizing compiler option.

I use a boost::lockfree class, spsc_queue where you can to specify the maximum (fixed size) of a lock free queue at compile time.

```
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<DBG_Data*, boost::lockfree::capacity<1024*1024> > _ringQueue;
```

With the same compiler options, vs 2017 produces a  dll of huge size.
Changing the the optimizing option from /O2 (speed) to /O1 (size) only for the source containing that line, I reduce the dll size to normal values.